# Sort an array of struct with generic size

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am new to C and I guess my code is far away of best practice..

I have an Array of struct in my C programm. The size of the array is 255 (allocated) but not all of it is used.

the Array in my eample is filled with following vaues:

```
2;a;121212;121212;0
9;c;121212;121212;1
6;d;121212;121212;1
4;e;121212;121212;1
1;v;121212;121212;1
8;x;121212;121212;1
```

the rest is filled with null values.. (I guess)

Now my problem is not with the actual sorting. It's when I start sorting, it will come to the point of taking an empty Index of my Array and faulting.

the array of books:

```
struct book{
    int ID;
    char name[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char dateIn[DATE_LEN];
    char dateOut[DATE_LEN];
    int isIn;
};


/* array of my books */
struct book books[MAX_BOOKS];
```

The sorting function:

```
void sort()
{
    /* first find out how many indexes there are */
    int h;
    for (h = 0; h< MAX_BOOKS; h++)
    {
        if (books[h].ID == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    int j =  0;

    int swaped = 1;
    struct book temp;
    while (swaped == 1)       //bubble sort on the book name
    {
        for(j=0;j< h ;j++)
        {
            swaped = 0;
            if(strcmp(books[j].name,books[j + 1].name)>0)
            {

                //copy to temp val
                temp.ID = books[j].ID;
                strcpy(temp.name,books[j].name);
                strcpy(temp.dateIn,books[j].dateIn);
                strcpy(temp.dateOut,books[j].dateOut);
                temp.isIn = books[j].isIn;


                //copy next val
                books[j].ID = books[j + 1].ID;
                strcpy(books[j].name,books[j + 1].name);
                strcpy(books[j].dateIn,books[j + 1].dateIn);
                strcpy(books[j].dateOut,books[j + 1].dateOut);
                books[j].isIn = books[j + 1].isIn;


                //copy back temp val
                books[j + 1].ID = temp.ID;
                strcpy(books[j+ 1].name,temp.name);
                strcpy(books[j + 1].dateIn,temp.dateIn);
                strcpy(books[j + 1].dateOut,temp.dateOut);
                books[j + 1].isIn = temp.isIn;


                swaped = 1;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

So my question would be if its possible to sort only values with where the ID is not 0?

If you need more information, I will try to deliver..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(j=0;j< h ;j++)
{
    if(strcmp(books[j].name,books[j + 1].name)>0)
    {
```

Here you are taking `j` from `0` to `h-1`, inclusive. So you are trying to compare for `j == h-1` the last element `books[j]` with the next one `books[j+1]`, which does not exist. You probably only want to check up to the pair `h-2`/`h-1`, that is `for(j=0; j<h-1; j++)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its difficult to choose one answer, because all together helped me!

Answer (score 2):

Why you are doing such big calculation for swaping? why dont you just do

```
if(strcmp(books[j].name,books[j + 1].name)>0){

   temp = books[j];
   books[j] = books[j+1];
   books[j+1] = temp;
}
```

And it is possible to sort your structure array. If you are able to do swaping on struct then you can do any kind of sorting algorithm.

change this condition `if(strcmp(books[j].name,books[j + 1].name)>0)` to  `if(books[j].ID>books[j + 1].id)` then you can sort the struct with respect to `ID`.

But follow the @Nabla's answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Nabla's answer is right. Also, you set `swapped = 0;` at the wrong place. You have:

```
while (swapped == 1)       //bubble sort on the book name
{
    for (j = 0; j < h; j++)
    {
        swapped = 0;
```

but you want:

```
while (swapped == 1)       //bubble sort on the book name
{
    swapped = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < h; j++)
    {
```